# Data output in a single row by order of importance

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get data that is on multiple rows into a single row by order of importance.

I was working with multiple tables and was able to pull all the data I need into one table - so currently I'm working with one table where the data I need exists in multiple rows. Example a person can have more than one role.  However, the roles have an order of importance - I added an order of importance column to the file I'm working with.

The file I'm working with looks like this:

```
ID      | FIRST   |LAST     | ROLE      | ORDER OF IMPORTANCE  
116     | Jamie   | Ansto   | PARAL     | 5  
116     | Jamie   | Ansto   | FMREMP    | 11    
153     | Alan    | Rond    | PAR       | 3  
153     | Alan    | Rond    | PARAL     | 5  
155     | Maureen | Aron    | GP        | 4  
155     | Maureen | Aron    | PARAL     | 5  
38      | William | Dry     | STU       | 8  
175     | Nathan  |Gong     | OTH       | 10  
175     |Nathan   |Gong     | FMRSTU    | 13  
175     |Nathan   | Gon     | FR        | 14  
308     | Bridget | Abad    | PAR       | 3  
308     | Bridget | Abad    | EMP       | 7  
370     | Matt    | Bodie   | BD        | 1  
370     | Matt    | Bodie   | AL        | 2
```

What I need is a file that has all the codes associated with one person on the same row in the order of their importance.
I want to end up with something that looks like this:

```
ID      |FIRST   |LAST    |CODE1   |CODE2   |CODE3   |CODE4   
116     |Jamie   |Ansto   |PARAL   |FMREMP  
153    |Alan     |Rond    |PAR     |PARAL  
155    |Maureen |Aron     | GP     | PARAL  
381    |William |Dry      |STU  
175    |Nathan   |Gong    |OTH     |FMRSTU  |FR  
308    | Bridget |Abad    |PAR     |EMP  
370   | Matt     |Bodie   |BD      | AL
```

I tried using  Group_Concat but it didn't give me the results in the order I wanted.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
MG

Comment: Tip: you can add an `ORDER BY` clause inside your group concat.

Comment: Do you have a set number of roles? If so, you could do a `PIVOT`.

Comment: No, I didn't try the ORDER BY clause.   @Zack, I do have a set number of roles.

Comment: The Group_concat and Order BY gave me this output:  
id, first, last, role, role, role, role, role... in a single column  where role are the different roles.  Not the output I need.

Comment: `ORDER OF IMPORTANCE` is a field from the table?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT *,GROUP_CONCAT(`ROLE` ORDER BY `ORDER_OF_IMPORTANCE` SEPARATOR ' ' ) 
FROM `table1` GROUP BY `ID`;
```

The `SEPARATOR ' '` function will give you result like this `OTH  FMRSTU  FR`. If you remove it and only do `GROUP_CONCAT(ROLE ORDER BY ORDER_OF_IMPORTANCE)`, the result will look like this `OTH,FMRSTU,FR` instead.

Comment: So I tried the above and here is the result it gave me:
just one ID  First   Last  Role  
and just one repeated role separated by commas (had to add the comma as a separator).  
example:
12 John Smith FR,FR,FR,FR,FR,FR,FR,FR,...
I added a distinct to the group_concat and I got one record
12 John Smith OTH,FRMSTU, FR, and every other role in the file attached to this record.

Comment: I was able to get what you posted to work - I massaged the data in excel to get the right format.  Thanks!